# Having trouble accessing a Nodejs server from a VPS (Express)

Tags: node.js, express

I am studying Android and I want to build an App that uses socket.io. I set up a VPS so can access the socket.io server from the android app I make it easier for me to study. I am having trouble accessing the VPS.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(null, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3009, "0.0.0.0");
app.get("/teste", function(req, res){
    res.send("olá");
});

io.on("connection", function (client) {
    console.log("conectado");
});
```

I tried to access

My_VPS_IP:3009/teste

but it doesn't work. Was it to work? What can I do? I used Nodejs extensively two years ago I never had problem. note: I didn't install any web server or made any configuration to the VPS. I only installed Nodejs and NPM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the VPS IP to `http`

```
http.listen(3009, VPS_IP);
```